# Server-side rendering of React-Bootstrap, unexpected token error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, server-side, react-bootstrap

I am trying to re-write the `React` code to use mostly server-side rendering and I faced an issue with `React-Bootstrap`. Switching from `import Grid from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Grid';` to `var Grid = require('react-bootstrap/lib/Grid');` gives an error in `render` method:

[image]

How should the importing of the `React-Bootstrap` components should be done then? Is it possible at all for `React-Bootstrap`? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you need to stringify the HTML.

Comment: This might help you. Check renderToString

https://hackernoon.com/server-side-rendering-with-create-react-app-1faf5a9d1eff

Comment: I think JSX should be inside `( )` . `return (<Grid> ...)`

Comment: @DarknessZX, I think you are right.

Comment: Nikita, Can you please provide the code also?

Answer (score 0):

I think this particular issue is solved. The error is gone after running `npm install babel-register`, `npm install babel-preset-react` and adding the following code at the top that tries to create `DOM` element out of `ScatterChart`

```
require('babel-register')({
    presets: ['react']
});
```

I found it here: https://medium.com/@remarkablemark/server-side-rendering-with-react-46715f501651

Very important is to define the `presets` above all of the import statements, at the very top of the file, otherwise the error is not going away.